# Google Autopilot cluster: unschedulable pods

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I created a pod with resource/limits in autopilot cluster:

```
    Limits:
      cpu:                500m
      ephemeral-storage:  1Gi
      memory:             512Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:                500m
      ephemeral-storage:  1Gi
      memory:             512Mi
```

But based on what I read everything should be configured automatically. And I don't see how could I add new nodes to cluster.

```
  Warning  FailedScheduling   2m39s (x3979 over 4d3h)  gke.io/optimize-utilization-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient memory, 3 Insufficient cpu.
  Normal   NotTriggerScaleUp  85s (x68738 over 4d5h)   cluster-autoscaler                     pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added): 2 node(s) didn't match node selector
```

Google console shows possible actions:

```
Increase maximum size limit for autoscaling in one or more node pools that have autoscaling enabled.
```

but this is autopilot and accroding to documentation it should be done automatically and I cannot do that at all. Very weird.

Comment: Have you tried just setting resource request w/o limits?  Autopilot will automagically set limit equal to request (and you can't have a limit > request).

Comment: Can you share the service YAML description?

Comment: Can you share the output of the following command: `kubectl get all --all-namespaces`?
It could be helpful for have a better grasp on the matter if you follow the [autopilot cluster guide](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/creating-an-autopilot-cluster#create_an_autopilot_cluster)

Comment: Same issue here! Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Nahuel I have the same issue as the OP but when I run that command, it errors out with "Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 172.16.251.210:443: i/o timeout"... other attempts fail the same way.  even `kubectl version` fails... any thought?

Comment: For others who see a similar issue, the root cause is likely **not** the same as the OP. I'd suggest asking your own question, and including your Pod YAML so myself and others can take a look.

Answer (score 3):

This is hard to debug precisely without seeing your Podspec YAML. Getting a `NotTriggerScaleUp` message however means that Autopilot will *never* add nodes for these pods and they will be stuck in Pending. Likely this is because there are conditions that can't be satisfied by the the autoscaler adding new nodes.

An example of an unsatisfiable condition would be a node-selector where the Pod is requesting to be placed in a zone that doesn't exist. Since the autoscaler can't create a node in a non-existent node, that Pod will forever sit in Pending.

When the autoscaler *can* provision resources for your Pod, you will see a `TriggeredScaleUp` message (typically within ~10 seconds of the Pod entering the Pending state, but it could take a minute in some cases).

I wrote up a more general explanation of [how pending pods work in Autopilot](https://wdenniss.com/autopilot-pending-pods), and what you can look for.

Comment: FYI the link https://wdenniss.com/autopilot-pending-pods is broken, citing that "There has been a critical error on this website."

Comment: Thanks @iamyojimbo, it was fixed 