# Are there any circumstances under which autopilot's scheduler would refuse to add a node to satisfy a pod's resource request, even if possible?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, autopilot

I've seen instances in our autopilot clusters where pods stay stuck in a pending state for a long time. In autoscale logs, the messages only indicate that no current nodes can satisfy the constraints on the pod - there is no explanation for why a new node wouldn't simply be scheduled.

For example the logs may indicate at existing nodes have incompatible taint, or zone, or w/e - but none of that explains why the autoscaler doesnt just add a new node (and a new instance group if necessary).

My guess is the pods are over-constrained and adding a node would impact utilization too much. Is there any way to recover this or some other reason in the logs?

Comment: Maybe it's a quota issue in your project ? Did you check the Quotas page to see if you are reaching the limits for cpu, memory or disks?

Comment: You should definitely get an error as to why a new node cannot be added if that is the case.  Also ... in the pod logs you should see a messages with something like "triggered scale up" ... if not, then there is something else going on for sure.

Comment: Checked quota and all the usual things. Im wondering if we know whether autopilot ever refuses to scale up for Efficiency and Cost Optimization reasons. Ex. if the node would end up being too underutilized, might it refuse to scale up.

Answer (score 0):

An example of an unsatisfiable condition would be a node-selector where the Pod is requesting to be placed in a zone that doesn't exist. Since the autoscaler can't create a node in a non-existent node, that Pod will forever sit in Pending as  per [William Denniss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67031113/google-autopilot-cluster-unschedulable-pods).

You can check this [documentation](https://wdenniss.com/autopilot-pending-pods) as reference.